# Set Permissions in Custom Module

Tags: 7, users

I am writing a custom module for my Drupal 7 site. I have added the code to enable a configure form.

I want to restrict the config to admin users only, and some of the functions to another group of users. How do I go about doing this?

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_permission()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) in your module. This allows you to add a custom permission. For example:

```
return array(
  'your permission name' => array(
    'title' => t('your permission title'),
    'description' => t('Description.'),
  ),
);
```

Afterwards, go to the permission page and set the ticks where you need them.

Comment: How would I check in each function that the current user had the right permission?

Comment: Use the user_access() function. Fore example: user_access('your role name')

Comment: In hook_permissions(), you don't define roles, you define *permission*, which you then apply to roles. The code itself is correct, but you probably want to use a description of the permission instead of a role name there. E.g. "access mymodule adminstration pages".

Comment: @Rooneyl: Berdir is right. Sorry.